# Access query/combo box

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have three text fields in Microsoft Access. When the data is filled for all three fields it should autofill/populate another field. Is it possible to execute this and if so how?

Comment: You need to know that you need to be very specific about your requirements here. What if all 3 are filled, and then the user deselects/empties a field? Should the event only fire after the user enters something in the third box? Should they click a button (*this would be the easiest*)? So, yes it's possible, but the how is ambiguous at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Given the info you provided you should use the AfterUpdate event to trigger your code.
In order to ensure proper data insertion on each text box you should include in your AfterUpdate a check if the other two textboxes have data besides the current.
If all 3 textboxes have valid data then the autopopulate code should be executed

Comment: I understand the part about the AfterUpdate, now the check if, would that be a line of code like an if and else statement in the code builder or is that some kind of option I would have to select?